# for loop in javascript to access elements incrementally

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, nested, increment

I am preparing a chart in Javascript.
I have an array element named **groupedByWeek**
this groupedweek is derived from JSON data. Now i am having it in form of child arrays like this: `groupedByWeek = Object { 1: Array[4], 2: Array[7], 3: Array[3] }`

screenshot of console is here:
[image]

Now i want to parse each of  **groupedByWeek** elements for graph, for the following code:

```
function increment(){
    var i = groupedByWeek[1];
    barChart1.parse(i,"json");
    for (; i <= groupedByWeek.length; i++){
        barChart1.parse(i,"json");
    }
}
```

and

```
<input type="button" onClick="increment()" value="Next"/>
```

but this is not working!
Infact nothing is working out inside `for loop` while i am doing `console.log()`

If i am doing like this then it's working for 1st elemnt only!!:

```
var i = groupedByWeek[1];
barChart1.parse(i,"json");
```

please give me a hint how to work it out!

Comment: Couple of problems here.  var i = [array] is the same i used in your for loop?? That would be expecting a number, not an array object. Also you misspelled length.

Comment: crrected spelling mistake. thanks! yes 'i' is same though! this is just for [refrence](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for_om2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

- Your array is containing an object, not an index.
- You spelt `length` as `legnth`.

You should be attempting to iterate through your object, rather than an Array.  So you would do something along these lines:

*Javascript:*

```
for(var index in object) {
    // Do something.
}
```

*jQuery:*

```
$.each(object, function(index, value) {
    // Do something.
});
```

I believe that was your original goal, iterate your object not a collection of the items.

Comment: thanks greg for your approach! let me check and let you know asap!

Comment: can you please guide me to iterate each groupedByWeek object incrementally and assign each of them to separate variable 'i'